# stationarity of a nonconvex-constrained problem

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, non-convex-optimization

Suppose I want to solve

min $f(x)$ subject to $x\in \mathcal C$

where  $\mathcal C$ is nonconvex, and $f$ is smooth and convex. What would be an appropriate definition for stationarity?

If $\mathcal C$ were convex, the one that pops to mind is like a normal cone constraint: 
$x^*$ is stationary if

$$ -\langle\nabla f(x^*),x-x^*\rangle \leq 0,\;\forall x\in \mathcal C.$$

So an easy approach may be to just replace $\mathcal C$ with the convex hull of $\mathcal C$. However, this is clearly a bad idea for most hard nonconvex problems. Take $\mathcal C = \{-1,1\}$ and $f(x) = x^2$. Then either -1 or 1 are minimal solutions, but are not stationary points according to this definition.

Answer (score 1):

For stationarity, you only need to check locally feasible directions. So I think you might be able to use a definition like this: There exists a $\delta>0$ such that
\begin{align}
f'(x; d)\geq 0,
\end{align}
for all feasible local perturbation directions $\|d\|\leq \delta$. Note that $f'(x; d)$ is the directional derivative, which if the function is smooth becomes $\nabla f(x)^T d$. Feasible local perturbations are the ones for which $x+d \in C$. You might want to think a bit more about this, as in the case where the set is non-convex some weird stuff could happen. Plus, I am not sure if this would be easy to check if the set is really weird.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the start! My weirdest two sets are sign vectors $\mathcal C = \{-1,1\}^n$ and the euclidean "shell" $\mathcal C = \{x : \|x\|_2 = 1\}$. In the case of the sign vectors especially, this definition seems to suggest any point in $\mathcal C$ is locally optimal, since they are all isolated. The optimization is done over all of $\mathbb R^n$ though, just with rounding at each iteration. But I guess this set is already "too weird"? Haha. .

Comment: @Y.S. The natural generalization is through tangent cones. At any candidate solution $x^* \in \mathcal{C}$, a necessary optimality condition is that $\nabla f(x^*)^{\text{T}} d  \geq 0$ for all $d$ in the tangent cone at $x^*$ (assuming $f$ is differentiable). Of course, this is not sufficient, and the KKT conditions provide a sharper condition under additional assumptions.

Comment: So, in the quadratic-over-binary example, the tangent cone if $x* = 1$ is $\{x : x \leq 1\}$, which includes 0, which is the only point that optimality condition holds. However, $0\not\in \mathcal C$. I think you're right in terms of natural candidates, but it seems like that's still not really a super useful condition in this case.

Comment: It's possible this problem is just too ill-posed. I appreciate the discussion!

Comment: @Y.S. If you are talking about $\underset{x \in \{-1,1\}}{\min} x^2$, then the tangent cone at $x^* = 1$ is simply the empty set (at least with the definition I'm using), so the necessary optimality condition holds (note that it is necessary). In this case (and in general, at an isolated point), the condition is strict.

Comment: Right I believe according to that definition, optimizing  any smooth function over any discrete set, the entire discrete set is the set of stationary points. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. And it isn't technically wrong - all feasible points are local minima when the feasible region is discrete.

Comment: When you have discrete set, then the stationarity does not give you that much info and as madnessweasley said every point would be stationary. This is because on a discrete set you do not have any topology and locality does not mean that much and stationarity is defined only based on local information. Having said that, you could define a graph on the points and have some local stationary on the graph, based on neighbors but I don't know if it would useful for you (it would be just a point having smaller objective than its neighbors, and does not depend on the gradient)

Comment: But the other set, i.e $C=\{x | \|x\|=1\}$, is very well-behaved. And you could basically get stationarity when $|\nabla f(x)^Tx| = \|\nabla f(x)\|\|x\|$. This is typical of any manifold for which it is not difficult to define local stationarity just based on the gradient of the function and the normal to the manifold.